# How to query the age of PostgreSQL advisory locks?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mutex

How could you query the age of advisory locks in PostgreSQL?

The purpose is to regularly run a job to unlock any stale advisory locks that haven't been unlocked after a certain time.

(Alternatively, is there a way to set a timeout for a pg advisory lock such that it auto-unlocks after the timeout if it hasn't already been unlocked?)

Comment: Advisory locks will be automatically unlocked either when the transaction ends (xact locks) or when the session (pid) ends. Do you really want to unlock them, or do you want to kill the pid?

Comment: "Like all locks in PostgreSQL, a complete list of advisory locks currently held by any session can be found in the pg_locks system view." it's in the PostgreSQL manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html section "13.3.5. Advisory Locks" But it looks like there is no created timestamp column within view pg_locks but only a pid which might be joinable with pg_stat_activity to find the age (backend_start)